# Errors when I open terminal after trying to install Metasploit

Tags: command-line, ruby

I tried installing Metasploit on Ubuntu 16, using this [webpage](http://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-in-ubunt). Following the instructions, I got the following error

```
sudo: exec: command not found
```

While downloading Ruby rbenv, I forgot to do the Framework install, so I went back to it, but then every time I open the terminal, I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means you have some incorrectly formatted lines in your `~/.bashrc` file.

It looks like you might have copied + pasted incorrectly under the section on **installing ruby using rbenv**.

The easiest way to solve this is to edit your `.bashrc` file and either correct or remove the lines the tutorial inserted.

**What your `.bashrc` should contain (according to the tutorial):**

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
```

Once you have that you make use of it by issuing the command `$ source .bashrc`.

I have no idea if the tutorial is correct so even if you match the content you might not get things working. In that case remove these lines and again issue `$ source .bashrc`.

**Just in case you have to recreate your .bashrc file** you can do the following :

`/bin/cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/`

Again you need to source the replacement:

`source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I don't seem to have a .bashrc file in my home directory or root folder, i think i must have deleted it incorrectly. Is there anyway i can possibly recreate it?

Comment: Are you sure? Are you viewing hidden files?

Comment: Edited answer to recreate bashrc

Comment: Ok, thank you. Problem was solved, all my errors disappeared from the terminal.

Comment: that's great. If my answer was correct can you accept it? If the solution was something else it's helpful to add it as an answer yourself -> it's useful for people searching for similar problems in the future.